# Try statement in nested for-loop to bypass errors (syntax error )

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, syntax-error, try-catch

I have a data frame with the text entries `dataframe['text']` as well as a list of features to compute for the function. Although not all features work for all text entries, so I was trying to compute everything possible, without manually checking which one worked for which entry. So I wanted the loop to continue after the point where it errors:

```
with Processor('config.yaml', 'en') as doc_proc:
    try:
        for j in range (0,len(features)): 
            for i in range (0, len(dataframe['text'])) :
                doc = doc_proc.analyze(dataframe['text'][i], 'string')
                result = (doc.compute_features([features[j]]))
                dataframe.loc[dataframe.index[i], [features[j]]]  = list(result.values())
             except: 
            continue
```

but I got the `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. The loop without try works, so I understand it's the reason but can't seem to find the correct way to change the syntax

Comment: That's not how exceptions work. If an exception is raised, control passes immediately and irreversibly to the close enclosing `except` clause that matches the raised exception. You cannot resume control where the exception was raised.

Comment: `except:` has to be at the same indentation level as `try:`

Comment: `except` must be indented to match the `try` statement; it's not a statement or expression itself that can be nested *in* the body of the `try` clause.

Comment: You should put the `try` inside the loop. Then it will resume with the next item in the iteration.

Comment: Oh thank you so much guys, it looks like it went through. not sure if I will get what I need but at least no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `try/except` inside the loop. Then it will resume with the next iteration.

```
with Processor('config.yaml', 'en') as doc_proc:
    for feature in features: 
        for i in range (0, len(dataframe['text'])):
            try:
                doc = doc_proc.analyze(dataframe['text'][i], 'string')
                result = (doc.compute_features([feature]))
                dataframe.loc[dataframe.index[i], [feature]]  = list(result.values())
            except:
                pass
```